# Stratified random sampling from data frame

Tags: r, random, sampling

I have a data frame in the format:

```
head(subset)
# ants  0 1 1 0 1 
# age   1 2 2 1 3
# lc    1 1 0 1 0
```

I need to create new data frame with random samples according to age and lc. For example I want 30 samples from age:1 and lc:1, 30 samples from age:1 and lc:0 etc.

I did look at random sampling method like;

```
newdata <- function(subset, age, 30)
```

But it is not the code that I want.

Answer (score 55):

I would suggest using either `stratified` from my "splitstackshape" package, or `sample_n` from the "dplyr" package:

```
## Sample data
set.seed(1)
n <- 1e4
d <- data.table(age = sample(1:5, n, T), 
                lc = rbinom(n, 1 , .5),
                ants = rbinom(n, 1, .7))
# table(d$age, d$lc)
```

For `stratified`, you basically specify the dataset, the stratifying columns, and an integer representing the size you want from each group OR a decimal representing the fraction you want returned (for example, .1 represents 10% from each group).

```
library(splitstackshape)
set.seed(1)
out <- stratified(d, c("age", "lc"), 30)
head(out)
#    age lc ants
# 1:   1  0    1
# 2:   1  0    0
# 3:   1  0    1
# 4:   1  0    1
# 5:   1  0    0
# 6:   1  0    1

table(out$age, out$lc)
#    
#      0  1
#   1 30 30
#   2 30 30
#   3 30 30
#   4 30 30
#   5 30 30
```

For `sample_n` you first create a grouped table (using `group_by`) and then specify the number of observations you want. If you wanted proportional sampling instead, you should use `sample_frac`.

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
out2 <- d %>%
  group_by(age, lc) %>%
  sample_n(30)

# table(out2$age, out2$lc)
```

Comment: And if you need both the sampled and non-sampled sets be returned (as was my case when creating a treatment/control split in an A/B test) the `bothSets = T` argument of the `stratified` method is your friend.

Comment: Is it possible to get 100% for age=1, 30% for age=2, etc ? (vary the final sample per group)

Comment: As of 2020, the `sample_n` and `sample_frac` functions have been deprecated and replaced with `slice_sample`, which can be used after the `group_by` call like so: `slice_sample(n = 30` or `slice_sample(prop = .5)`

Answer (score 17):

See the function `strata` from the package [sampling](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sampling/index.html). The function selects stratified simple random sampling and gives a sample as a result. Extra two columns are added - inclusion probabilities (`Prob`) and strata indicator (`Stratum`). See the example.

```
require(data.table)
require(sampling)

set.seed(1)
n <- 1e4
d <- data.table(age = sample(1:5, n, T), 
                lc = rbinom(n, 1 , .5),
                ants = rbinom(n, 1, .7))

# Sort
setkey(d, age, lc)

# Population size by strata
d[, .N, keyby = list(age, lc)]
#     age lc    N
#  1:   1  0 1010
#  2:   1  1 1002
#  3:   2  0  993
#  4:   2  1 1026
#  5:   3  0 1021
#  6:   3  1  982
#  7:   4  0  958
#  8:   4  1  940
#  9:   5  0 1012
# 10:   5  1 1056

# Select sample
set.seed(2)
s <- data.table(strata(d, c("age", "lc"), rep(30, 10), "srswor"))

# Sample size by strata
s[, .N, keyby = list(age, lc)]
#     age lc  N
#  1:   1  0 30
#  2:   1  1 30
#  3:   2  0 30
#  4:   2  1 30
#  5:   3  0 30
#  6:   3  1 30
#  7:   4  0 30
#  8:   4  1 30
#  9:   5  0 30
# 10:   5  1 30
```

Comment: What if I want to split a dataset into two "equal" groups based on two or three variables?

Comment: @user3116753, this seems to be out of scope question. Please define it as a new question.

Comment: Not needed anymore. Used K-means achieve this

Answer (score 17):

Here's some data:

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 1e4
d <- data.frame(age = sample(1:5,n,TRUE), 
                lc = rbinom(n,1,.5),
                ants = rbinom(n,1,.7))
```

You want a split-apply-combine strategy, where you `split` your data.frame (`d` in this example), sample rows/observations from each subsample, and then combine then back together with `rbind`. Here's how it works:

```
sp <- split(d, list(d$age, d$lc))
samples <- lapply(sp, function(x) x[sample(1:nrow(x), 30, FALSE),])
out <- do.call(rbind, samples)
```

The result:

```
> str(out)
'data.frame':   300 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ age : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ lc  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ants: int  1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
> head(out)
         age lc ants
1.0.2242   1  0    1
1.0.4417   1  0    1
1.0.389    1  0    0
1.0.4578   1  0    1
1.0.8170   1  0    1
1.0.5606   1  0    1
```

Comment: that's what I want to do. I did try split and lapply functions, but r gives an exceed memory error. Is there other way to do it for huge dataset? thanks

Comment: @user3525533 How big is your dataset?

Comment: its around 2gb. I have 30 variables and 16826950 obs. in my data frame though. When I use split function, it gives a memory error.

Comment: Sorry, it's `setDT(d)[d[, sample(.I, 30L, FALSE), by="age,lc"]$V1]`

Comment: @Thomas;it will be faster to sample the row indices rather than rows - a lot faster if there are many columns / rows. `sp <- split(seq_len(nrow(d)), list(d$age, d$lc)) ; samples <- lapply(sp, sample, 30) ; d[unlist(samples), ]`

Answer (score 7):

Here's a one-liner using `data.table`:

```r
set.seed(1)
n <- 1e4
d <- data.table(age  = sample(1:5, n, T),
                lc   = rbinom(n,   1, .5),
                ants = rbinom(n,   1, .7))

out <- d[, .SD[sample(1:.N, 30)], by=.(age, lc)]

# Check
out[, table(age, lc)]
##    lc
## age  0  1
##   1 30 30
##   2 30 30
##   3 30 30
##   4 30 30
##   5 30 30
```

Comment: This is a great answer for a fast and convenient way to stratify.

Answer (score 3):

This is ridiculously easy to do with base R.

Step 1: Create a stratum indicator using the `interaction` function.

Step 2: Use `tapply` on a sequence of row indicators to identify the indices of the random sample.

Step 3: Subset the data with those indices

Using the data example from @Thomas:

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 1e4
d <- data.frame(age = sample(1:5,n,TRUE), 
                lc = rbinom(n,1,.5),
                ants = rbinom(n,1,.7))

## stratum indicator
d$group <- interaction(d[, c('age', 'lc')])

## sample selection
indices <- tapply(1:nrow(d), d$group, sample, 30)

## obtain subsample
subsampd <- d[unlist(indices, use.names = FALSE), ]
```

Verify appropriate stratification

```
> table(subsampd$group)

1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 1.1 2.1 3.1 4.1 5.1 
 30  30  30  30  30  30  30  30  30  30
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an updated `dplyr` version for stratified sampling when you need different numbers of samples from each group (i.e. 1:5 ratio or something in my case, but you can specify the n for each group combination).

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 1e4
d <- tibble::tibble(age = sample(1:5, n, T), 
                    lc = rbinom(n, 1 , .5),
                    ants = rbinom(n, 1, .7))
> d
# A tibble: 10,000 x 3
     age    lc  ants
   <int> <int> <int>
 1     2     0     1
 2     2     1     1
 3     3     1     1
 4     5     0     1
 5     2     0     1
 6     5     0     1
 7     5     1     1
 8     4     1     1
 9     4     1     1
10     1     0     1
# … with 9,990 more rows
```

there are 10 unique combos of age/lc:

```
> d %>% group_by(age, lc) %>% nest()
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   age, lc [10]
     age    lc data                
   <int> <int> <list>              
 1     2     0 <tibble [993 × 1]>  
 2     2     1 <tibble [1,026 × 1]>
 3     3     1 <tibble [982 × 1]>  
 4     5     0 <tibble [1,012 × 1]>
 5     5     1 <tibble [1,056 × 1]>
 6     4     1 <tibble [940 × 1]>  
 7     1     0 <tibble [1,010 × 1]>
 8     1     1 <tibble [1,002 × 1]>
 9     4     0 <tibble [958 × 1]>  
10     3     0 <tibble [1,021 × 1]>
```

We can sample a prespecified number of rows from each group of age/lc combinations:

```
> d %>% 
  group_by(age, lc) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  # you must supply `n` for each combination of groups in `group_by(age, lc)`
  mutate(n = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1)) %>%  
  mutate(samp = purrr::map2(.x = data, .y= n, 
                            .f = function(.x, .y) slice_sample(.data = .x, n = .y))) %>% 
  select(-data, -n) %>% 
  unnest(samp)
# A tibble: 16 x 3
     age    lc  ants
   <int> <int> <int>
 1     2     0     0
 2     2     1     1
 3     3     1     1
 4     5     0     0
 5     5     0     1
 6     5     1     1
 7     5     1     1
 8     5     1     1
 9     4     1     1
10     1     0     1
11     1     0     1
12     1     1     1
13     1     1     1
14     1     1     0
15     4     0     1
16     3     0     1
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner using my function `fslice_sample()`. .

The syntax is tidy-based but the grouping is done using a mix of `collapse` and `data.table`.

It's also a bit more flexible than `dplyr::slice_sample()`.

```r
# remotes::install_github("NicChr/timeplyr")
library(timeplyr)

fslice_sample(d, n = 30, .by = c(age, lc), seed = 1)
#> # A tibble: 300 x 3
#>      age    lc  ants
#>  * <int> <int> <int>
#>  1     1     0     1
#>  2     1     0     1
#>  3     1     0     0
#>  4     1     0     0
#>  5     1     0     0
#>  6     1     0     1
#>  7     1     0     1
#>  8     1     0     0
#>  9     1     0     0
#> 10     1     0     0
#> # ... with 290 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following approach. Using sampling you can get the index for which set the sample is in. If you want to stratify this sampling, it is not possible using sampling() in R. Therefore I created a function, using the splitTools package :

```
library("splitTools")
stratified_sampling <- function(y_values, k_folds, set_seed = 54321) {
  index_array <- rep(0,length(y_values))
  CVfolds <- create_folds(y_values, k = k_folds, type = "stratified", seed=set_seed)
  for(i in 1:k_fold) {
    index_array[!c(1:length(y_values)) %in% CVfolds[[i]]] <- i
  }
  return(index_array)
}
```