# Sampling from a data.frame while controlling for a proportion [stratified sampling]

Tags: r, sampling

I have the following dataset

```
id1<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
status<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
df<-data.frame(id1,status)
```

In `df` for 40% of my observations `status` is '2'.
I am looking for a function to extract a sample of 10 observations from `df` while maintaining the above proportion.

I have already seen [stratified random sampling from data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23479512/stratified-random-sampling-from-data-frame-in-r) but it is not talking about the proportions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the `stratified` function from my "splitstackshape" package:

```
library(splitstackshape)
stratified(df, "status", 10/nrow(df))
#     id1 status
#  1:   5      1
#  2:  12      1
#  3:   2      1
#  4:   1      1
#  5:   6      1
#  6:   9      1
#  7:  16      2
#  8:  17      2
#  9:  18      2
# 10:  15      2
```

Alternatively, using `sample_frac` from "dplyr":

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(status) %>%
  sample_frac(10/nrow(df))
```

Both of these would take a stratified sample proportional to the original grouping variable (hence the use of `10/nrow(df)`, or, equivalently, `0.5`).

Comment: Quick question @Ananda Mahto. is this sampling method going to be with replacement?

Comment: @AliCivil, you can specify this with the replace argument (default=FALSE - see the help of the function). Add `replace=TRUE` if you want to have replacement: `stratified(df, "status", 10/nrow(df), replace=TRUE)`.