# Repeated random sampling and kurtosis on unbalanced sample

Tags: r

I have an unbalanced dataset with people from liberal and conservative background giving rating on an issue (1-7). Would like to see how polarized the issue is.

The sample is heavily skewed towards liberal (70% of the sample). How do I do repeated sampling using R to create a balanced sample (50-50) and calculate kurtosis?

For example, I have total 50 conservatives. How do I randomly sample 50 liberals out of 150 repeatedly?

A sample dataframe below:

```
  political_ort   rating  
    liberal         1 
    liberal         6 
    conservative    5   
    conservative    3   
    liberal         7  
    liberal         3 
    liberal         1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sampling from a data.frame while controlling for a proportion \[stratified sampling\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29360799/sampling-from-a-data-frame-while-controlling-for-a-proportion-stratified-sampli)

Comment: Thanks! Not really. I'm looking to sample the same number of liberals as conservatives. So if there are 10 conservatives, would like to sample 10 from 70 liberals repeatly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing is termed 'undersampling'. Here is one method using tidyverse functions:

```
# Load library
library(tidyverse)

# Create some 'test' (fake) data
sample_df <- data_frame(id_number = (1:100),
                        political_ort = c(rep("liberal", 70),
                                          rep("conservative", 30)),
                        ratings = sample(1:7, size = 100, replace = TRUE))

# Take the fake data
undersampled_df <- sample_df %>% 
# Group the data by category (liberal / conservative) to treat them separately
  group_by(political_ort) %>% 
# And randomly sample 30 rows from each category (liberal / conservative)
  sample_n(size = 30, replace = FALSE) %>%
# Because there are only 30 conservatives in total they are all included
# Finally, ungroup the data so it goes back to a 'vanilla' dataframe/tibble
  ungroup()
# You can see the id_numbers aren't in order anymore indicating the sampling was random
```

There is also the ROSE package that has a function ("ovun.sample") that can do this for you: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ROSE/versions/0.0-3/topics/ovun.sample