# Stratified random sampling from data frame_follow up

Tags: r, random, sampling

I am trying to randomly sample 50% of the data for each of the group following [Stratified random sampling from data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23479512/stratified-random-sampling-from-data-frame). A reproducible example using mtcars dataset in R looks like below. What I dont understand is, the sample index clearly shows a group of gear labeled as '5', but when the index is applied to the mtcars dataset, the sampled data mtcars2 does not contain any record from gear='5'. What went wrong? Thank you very much.

```
> set.seed(14908141)
> index=tapply(1:nrow(mtcars),mtcars$gear,function(x){sample(length(x),length(x)*0.5)})
> index
$`3`
[1]  6  7 14  4 12  9 13

$`4`
[1] 12  7  8  4  6  5

$`5`
[1] 5 1

> mtcars2=mtcars[unlist(index),]
> table(mtcars2$gear)

 3  4 
12  3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the approach you've done creates a number `1:length(mtcars$gear)` for each `gear`  group so you will have repeat row numbers for each group. Then, when you subset it isn't working, see in your output above you have row number `7` in both `gear` group `3` and `4`.

**Base R**

I would use `split` first to split by gear:

```
res <- split(mtcars, mtcars$gear)
```

then I run over this list using `lapply` and sample 50% of them that way:

```
res2 <- lapply(res, function(x) {
  x[sample(1:nrow(x), nrow(x)*0.5, FALSE), ]
    }
)
```

if you would like one dataset at the end (instead of a list) you can combine using `do.call`:

```
final_df <- do.call(rbind, res2)
```

**dplyr**

A simpler approach would be:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  sample_frac(., 0.5)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. I noticed the problem that same record was included in more than one group. Is it possible to correct my code above with tapply() or some other base R function?

Comment: see a base type solution above

Comment: do.call(), thats exactly what I need, thank you very much.