# Data partitioning based on timeseries and groups in R

Tags: r, time-series, partitioning

I need to split a large dataframe of meterological timeseries into a training and validation samples. It contains data from multiple stations, which have varying period of observations. How could I divide it so that proportion of training and validation observations is equal across each station. Given the following dataset:

| Station | Date | temp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2012-01-01 | -0.8 |
| A | 2012-01-02 | 0.1 |
| A | 2012-01-03 | 0.5 |
| A | 2012-01-04 | 0.4 |
| B | 2012-01-01 | 0.1 |
| B | 2012-01-02 | 0.5 |

and assuming that the training set should include only first 50% of the observations from each station, the desired output would be:

| Station | Date | temp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2012-01-01 | -0.8 |
| A | 2012-01-02 | 0.1 |
| B | 2012-01-01 | 0.1 |

Comment: Please do not post photos of data or code! If you do, people who are willing to help you would have to type out all that text. Instead proved a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) P.S. Here is [a good overview on how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stratified random sampling from data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23479512/stratified-random-sampling-from-data-frame)

Comment: @dario, thanx for the link, but it uses random/stratified partitioning whereas my question suggests that observations should be extracted as continuous sub-periods. Re your first comment, its not a code/prhoto, but I do accept that reproducible example is more appropriate. Sorry, Im a newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example you could use `slice_head` from dplyr. For creating the validation, remove the records that are in training. This to avoid selecting duplictates in case there is an uneven number of records for a station.

```
training <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date),
         id = row_number()) %>% 
  group_by(Station) %>% 
  slice_head(prop = 0.5)
  
validation <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date),
         id = row_number()) %>%
  filter(!id %in% training$id)

training
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   Station [2]
  Station Date        temp    id
  <chr>   <date>     <dbl> <int>
1 A       2012-01-01  -0.8     1
2 A       2012-01-02   0.1     2
3 B       2012-01-01   0.1     5

validation
  Station       Date temp id
1       A 2012-01-03  0.5  3
2       A 2012-01-04  0.4  4
3       B 2012-01-02  0.5  6
```

Comment: This works well, many thanx @phiver!